# Android webview append css to existing site

Tags: android, webview

I am using the webview as following

```
WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com");
```

It loads the page fine. Now I am trying to add a line head section of the page before it renders in the web view. e.g.

```
<style>.test{color:red}</style>
```

is it possible to add. if yes then how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using `evaluateJavascript`

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: document.getElementById('header').setAttribute('style','background-color: red;') ", new ValueCallback<String>() {
@Override
public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
  //in case you have some return value from your script
}
});
```